# .htaccess настройка (Tor)

Tags: php, tor

Ребят, подскажите как настроить .htaccess для Tor сети. Так как у меня mvc паттерн и нужно переадресовать все запросы на index.php.
Позже я решил его открыть, на сайте то есть http://xxxxxxx.onion/.htaccess
Я был шокирован, когда он мне предложил его скачать. В обычной сети(не тор), написало бы forbidden 403. Я так понял, что он попросту его не воспринимает как системный файл или в чем может быть проблема?

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^index.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L] 

RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^https$ 

RewriteRule .? - [E=HTTPS:on] 
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .?.php[? ].$" 
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404] 

Options -Indexes 
Options -Includes 
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) ./?%{QUERY_STRING} 

php_flag display_errors 1 
php_flag display_startup_errors 1 
php_value error_reporting 2047
```

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/100380

Comment: вы сами этот файл составляли? на дичь какую то похоже больше. и почему вы думаете, что если ваш хттп запрос пойдет обычным путем, а не через цепочку tor-узлов, то это хоть каким то малейшим образом повлияет на то, как апач отдаст ответ?

Comment: можете в целом сократить ваш вопрос до "почему я могу скачать .htaccess", и убрать эти пассажи про tor, mvc, и сам файл. сути проблемы это не изменит.

Comment: Нет, составлял не я брал готовые блоки. Но проблемы походу в сервере nginx, так как там, как я только узнал, не поддерживается .htaccess. И нужно переписывать эти правила под nginx

Comment: У вас сервер nginx вот его и конфигурируйте. .htaccess для него не используется.